# Upload Object (image file) to Linode Object Storage using PHP (Laravel) with S3Client

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-8, linode, object-storage

What could be the possible solution for this? I'm trying to upload an Object (Image file) to my Linode Object Storage, I have already set up the configuration and credentials but I'm still having trouble doing it. Can someone help me?

Code:

```
$config = [
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.region'),
        'scheme' => 'http',
        'endpoint' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.endpoint'),
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.key'),
            'secret' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.secret'),
        ],
        'debug' => true
    ];

    $client = new S3Client($config);
    
    return $client->putObject([
        'Bucket' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket'),
        'Key' => $filename,
        'SourceFile' => $file
    ]);
```

Here's the exception error:
[check me please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XozX8.png)

Hoping to have some feedback here, thank you!

Comment: whats the code that you have written to call that function - by the looks of it the parameter your passing is empty possibly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I updated it now